# How do I download KPPP-debs from within Windows?

Tags: installation, internet, broadband

How do I download KPPP even if I can only connect to the internet via dial-up connection?

In other words: is there a way to get KPPP while Windows is running and install it later on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the package at http://packages.ubuntu.com

For 13.04 for instance http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/kppp

You'd need to make sure that you have the dependencies installed.

Once you've downloaded the file(s) externally you can install them on the target machine.

Comment: what do you mean by "You'd need to make sure that you have the dependencies installed."?
what are even the dependencies?

Comment: have you actually looked at the kppp packages page - all the dependencies are shown there